# Suspended thread time

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I wanted to calculate the time between creating a thread and taking control by it, then compare this time for normal and suspended threads. But the results are quite chaotic.

[image]

So, my question is: Does it really makes sense? I think that instant resuming doesn't have a visible effect on the result.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

DWORDLONG freq;

DWORD WINAPI startThread(LPVOID lpParam) {
    DWORDLONG c_beg = *((DWORDLONG*)lpParam);
    DWORDLONG c_end;
    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&c_end);
    cout << (double(c_end - c_beg)) / (freq) << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    DWORDLONG c_beg;
    HANDLE iThread, sThread;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency((LARGE_INTEGER*)&freq);
    cout << "instant" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&c_beg);
        iThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)startThread, (LPVOID*)&c_beg, 0, NULL);
        WaitForSingleObject(iThread, INFINITE);
    }
    cout << "suspended" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&c_beg);
        sThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)startThread, (LPVOID*)&c_beg, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL);
        ResumeThread(sThread);
        WaitForSingleObject(sThread, INFINITE);
    }
    CloseHandle(iThread);
    CloseHandle(sThread);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect there to be any noticable difference - an unsuspended thread hasn't necessarily started when `CreateThread` returns, and changing the scheduling of the suspended thread during the next few nanoseconds after creating it won't matter.

Comment: Chaotic results are not too surprising, you're dealing with very small intervals on a system that's also doing other things then running your code. I even doubt QueryPerformanceCounter gives you the time resulotion you need. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/rdtsc?view=msvc-160) But that has issues with variable clockspeeds.

Comment: None of the output is meaningful. You are sharing global state across threads, and aren't coordinating access to it. The behavior of the code is undefined. The fact that you're leaking thread handles left and right doesn't help either. Now, that out of the way, what's the immediate *problem* you are trying to solve?

Comment: Makes total sense, especially since it's inefficient to immediately do the context switch to a new thread after creating it, especially since the thread that created it probably wants to set up some operation to block (like your WaitForSingleObject) anyway.  The designers of the operating system anticipated this in the general case, so that the scheduler won't thrash.